# Unable to send and retrieve data on load using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my code so please guys help me, I am new to ajax and I am unable to send and retrieve data on load.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function(){


       $(window).load(function(){
           alert("Everthing is fine");
              var tid = $('#$tid').val();
              var qnn = $('#$qnn').val();

           $.ajax({
             url:"testengine.php",
             type:"POST",
             async:false,
             data:{
               "testid":tid,
               "queno":qnn
             },
             success:function(html){
                $('#Que_Display').html(html);
             }

           })

       });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Any error message to provide ?

Comment: share `testengine.php` code ?

Comment: this is link for both file @Niklesh  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tkoi6ogbvnthafq/AAB4xuexDU6MPYBa0Qfb-ncNa?dl=0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code I think it will help you.

You got some thing wrong with the id name `$('#$tid')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   alert("Everthing is fine");
     var tid = $('#tid').val();
     var qnn = $('#qnn').val();

   $.ajax({
     url:"testengine.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{
       "testid":tid,
       "queno":qnn
     }
   }).done(function(html){
        $('#Que_Display').html(html);
   });


});
```